# PTIJ: Can a king ask someone wearing a Yale U. sweatshirt a war question?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The seal of [Yale University](http://archives.yalealumnimagazine.com/issues/01_03/seal.html) says אורים ותומים.

The *Urim Vetumim* was originally worn by the High Priest as part of the breastplate. Today, there is no High Priest, but, it seems that via the logo, we still have the Urim Vetumim.

Tanac"h records that several kings such as Sha'ul and David frequently asked the Urim Vetumim questions prior to going to war.

We currently have kings. If someone wore a Yale T-shirt or sweatshirt, could the king ask the (person wearing the) shirt a war-related question?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 3):

Of course he could! However, he might not have to listen to the answer.

Comment: Shouldn't that be a comment? I mean, you didn't exactly answer the question.

Comment: Maybe. I'm new, how exactly does it work here? I tried it now, and it didn't let me comment

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Hope to see you around!

Answer (score 2):

Rav Yonasan Eybshutz says that the reason Mordechai allowed himself to be dressed in בגדי מלכות was becausֵe only a king could destroy Amalek. This destruction was required before the Bais Hamikdash could be built. Thus, Haman had to be killed and his followers destroyed before Daryavesh (the son of Esther and Achashveros) could allow the Jews to build the second temple.

The question had to be asked by the king or his representative. As a result, nowadays, the question would have to be posed by Jared Kushner, who would be the closest in position to what Mordechai was during Purim.

However, the logo would have to be enlarged and the full letters that belong on the Urim Vetumim show clearly so that they can be read. Jared Kushner would then have to take the letters to someone like Rav Chaim Kanievsky to interpret.

Comment: Of course, as Kushner studied at Harvard, he would never ask a shailoh of a Yalie

Comment: @noach MiFrankfurt Well his wife is named Yael